# How to install the jenkins sonar plugin manually?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube

**How can I download and install the jenkins sonar (version 2.1) plugin to jenkins (version 1.532)?**

We cannot use the jenkins Update Center, as it failes to connect to the update site:

*hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/sonar/2.1/sonar.hpi*

Please note that opening the firewall to the update site is not an option we wish to consider - for security reasons, we want to do this process manually.

How can this plugin be installed manually?

tx

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's pretty straightforward:

- Manually download the HPI file with the [link you provided](http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/sonar/2.1/sonar.hpi)
- Then [install the HPI manually in your Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Byhand)

Comment: You can also deploy the config file hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.xml